# What's the difference between [adjective-phrase] and [phrasal-adjective]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What's the difference between [adjective-phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjective-phrase) and [phrasal-adjective](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrasal-adjective)?
Should they be merged?
Could we write some tag wiki/usage guidance to make any difference clearer?